# Looking for a way to plot the following correlation data using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, correlation

I'm trying to visualize the following data and would appreciate some advice. Basically I ran a bunch of correlations and want to visualize if variable A or variable B is more strongly correlated with Height, Weight, Volume, etc.

```
variable <- c('A','B','A','B','A','B')
outcome <- c('Height','Height','Weight', 'Weight', 'Volume', 'Volume')
correlation_coeff <- c(0.76, 0.65, 0.77,0.56,0.91,-0.34)
p_value<- c(0.04,0.03,0.01,0.02,0.001,0.09)

data <- data.frame(variable, outcome, correlation_coeff, p_value)
```

Since this is not a matrix of correlation coefficients (I never looked at the correlation between Height and Weight, for example) I'm not really sure what to do. Normally I just use the ggcorrplot() function but in this case it's obviously not going to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could plot the correlation plot directly with `geom_tile`, which closely resembles the look of `ggcorrplot`.

You can optionally have the p values overlaid:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(variable, outcome, fill = correlation_coeff)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("p =", p_value)), size = 10) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("blue", "white", "red"), limits = c(-1, 1)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 16)) +
  labs(fill = "Correlation coefficient") +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ggcorrplot() takes a matrix as an input, so you just need to turn your data into a matrix:

```
variable <- c('A','B')
outcome <- c('Height','Weight', 'Volume')
correlation_coeff <- c(0.76, 0.65, 0.77,0.56,0.91,-0.34)
p_value<- c(0.04,0.03,0.01,0.02,0.001,0.09)

data <- matrix(correlation_coeff, nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(variable,outcome))

ggcorplot(data)
```

That should make a 2x3 correlation chart in the style you're looking for.

Comment: This looks great. Thank you very much.